# Associate a value with a type in Haskell using a typeclass

Tags: haskell

I want to use a typeclass to return a `String` instance that is functionally dependent upon a Haskell type. For example, imagine we have the type `Form`. I want to associate the string "form" with this type. Given the type `Invocation`, I want to associate the string "job". And so on. The important thing is that *I will often not have an instance of the type in question, though the type will be in the type signature of any function that uses it.*

Perhaps an easy way to demonstrate this is with Swift:

```
protocol Resource {
  static var resourcePathSegment: String { get }
}

struct Form : Resource {
    static let resourcePathSegment = "form"
}

struct Invocation: Resource {
    static let resourcePathSegment = "job"
}

print(Form.resourcePathSegment)
```

Why would I want such a thing? I'm talking to a REST API that uses certain conventions. For a `GET` request, the path segment to the resource in question is functionally dependent upon the type of the data returned from the request. However, I won't have an instance of this type until the request completes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Proxy` type, from `Data.Proxy`, is defined as `data Proxy a = Proxy`.
This may be used to create a typeclass for this functionality:

```
class Resource a where
    name :: Proxy a -> String

instance Resource Form
    name _ = "form"

instance Resource Invocation where
    name _ = "job"

-- etc.
```

You can then get the `name` of a type by calling `name (Proxy :: Proxy type_name)`.

There are several variations of this technique; an excellent summary can be found at the recent blog post [Proxy arguments in class methods: a comparative analysis](https://ryanglscott.github.io/2019/02/06/proxy-arguments-in-class-methods/).

**EDIT:** I see that @Alexis King has submitted a very similar answer. Refer to the blog post above for an overview of the pros and cons of each approach. (Personally, I would use Alexis's technique, since I like `TypeApplications`, but I feel that mine is a bit simpler since it doesn't require `AllowAmbiguousTypes` or `TypeApplications` to use.)

Comment: The `TypeApplications` way is more modern, yours is more "classical".  Modern things can be great, but they can also have problems that only time will reveal.  (For example, `TypeApplications` is sensitive to minor changes in the type signature.  Will this be irritating in practice?  Don't know yet!)

Comment: Good point @luqui. On the other hand, these sort of minor signature changes wouldn't be too common with this sort of typeclass, and a type signature change would probably be a breaking change whether or not `TypeApplications` are used. Personally I find the `@`-syntax a lot more convenient than saying `Proxy :: Proxy something` every time.

Comment: Even when using proxies, I construct then by `Proxy @ SomeType`!

Comment: @Ben That's what I do too - `TypeApplications` is so _convenient_! `fromIntegral` is another one which benefits from the syntax.

Answer (score 11):

Using `TypeApplications`, this is easy:

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes, TypeApplications #-}

class Resource a where
  resourcePathSegment :: String

instance Resource Form where
  resourcePathSegment = "form"

instance Resource Invocation where
  resourcePathSegment = "job"
```

To illustrate how to use the above:

```
ghci> :t resourcePathSegment
resourcePathSegment :: Resource a => String
ghci> resourcePathSegment @Form
"form"
ghci> resourcePathSegment @Invocation
"job"
```

Comment: You may need to add `ScopedTypeVariables` in order to be able to use this type application with a type variable in an instance. See https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/19593