# Creating an array of things based on a type when you don't have an input parameter to tell you the type

Tags: haskell

I sometimes have a set of tests that I want to run on a bunch of different types. Here's a simple example of how I usually do that:

```
import           Test.Framework                                (Test)
import           Test.Framework.Providers.QuickCheck2          (testProperty)
import           Test.QuickCheck

additionCommutes :: (Eq a, Num a) => a -> a -> Bool
additionCommutes x y = x + y == y + x

divisionByItselfIsOne :: (Eq a, Ord a, Fractional a) => a -> Property
divisionByItselfIsOne x = x > 0 ==> x / x == 1
  -- pretend rounding errors won't occur, this is just an example


floatTests :: [Test]
floatTests = [
               testProperty "float addition commutes"
                 (additionCommutes :: Float -> Float -> Bool),
               testProperty "float divided by itself is 1"
                 (divisionByItselfIsOne :: Float -> Property)
             ]

doubleTests :: [Test]
doubleTests = [
               testProperty "double addition commutes"
                 (additionCommutes :: Double -> Double -> Bool),
               testProperty "double divided by itself is 1"
                 (divisionByItselfIsOne :: Double -> Property)
             ]
```

But I'd rather avoid the repetition of listing the tests for each type. (Perhaps there are a lot of tests involved.) I'd like to define the lists of tests once, and then instantiate it for each type. Something like this...

```
numberTests :: (Eq a, Ord a, Num a, Fractional a) => [Test] for the type "a"
numberTests = [
                testProperty "double addition commutes"
                  (additionCommutes :: a -> a -> Bool),
                testProperty "double divided by itself is 1"
                  (divisionByItselfIsOne :: a -> Property)
               ]


floatTests = numberTests :: [Test] for the type "float"

doubleTests = numberTests :: [Test] for the type "double"
```

Of course, that isn't valid Haskell. **I have a feeling there might be some magic type-level programming technique that I could use to accomplish this**. I skimmed Maguire's Thinking With Types but I still couldn't see how to solve this problem. Any suggestions?

If there's a technique that would work in principle, but wouldn't play nicely with QuickCheck's reflection stuff, that's fine -- I'm more interested in building my type-level programming skills than solving this particular problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Associate a value with a type in Haskell using a typeclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54603849/associate-a-value-with-a-type-in-haskell-using-a-typeclass)

Comment: @Noughtmare That's most of the answer, but don't we also need ScopedTypeVariables to be able to write `additionCommutes @a`?

Comment: By the way, `class Eq a => Ord a` means you don't need to include the `Eq` constraint in your `numberTests` type signature. Similarly for `Num`/`Fractional`.

Comment: @Noughtmare, I tried to do something like that, but I had trouble getting it to work. Daniel's answer is exactly what I hoped I could do, but I will also revisit that technique for my own education.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're quite close:

```
{-# Language AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# Language ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# Language TypeApplications #-}

--             vvvvvvvvv
numberTests :: forall a. (Eq a, Ord a, Num a, Fractional a) => [Test]
numberTests = -- just like in the question

--                        vvvvvvv
floatTests  = numberTests @Float
doubleTests = numberTests @Double
```

You don't even need to specifically name `floatTests` and `doubleTests`; you could write something like

```
allTests = numberTests @Float ++ numberTests @Double
```

if you wanted.